# how to generate graph from trace file in ns2?

Tags: tcl, ns2, awk

I am facing a problem in generating **xgraph from .tr file.** The error message is like this:

> Error in file `voip.tr' at line 610:
>
> Unknown line type
>
> Problems found with input data.

The format of .tr file is like this:

```
+ 1 0 1 sctp 56 -------I 0 0.0 3.0 1 -1 2 65535 65535
- 1 0 1 sctp 56 -------I 0 0.0 3.0 1 -1 2 65535 65535
r 1.01224 0 1 sctp 56 -------I 0 0.0 3.0 1 -1 2 65535 65535
+ 1.01224 1 3 sctp 56 -------I 0 0.0 3.0 1 -1 2 65535 65535
- 1.01224 1 3 sctp 56 -------I 0 0.0 3.0 1 -1 2 65535 65535
r 1.02448 1 3 sctp 56 -------I 0 0.0 3.0 1 -1 2 65535 65535
+ 1.02448 3 1 sctp 56 -------I 0 3.0 0.0 1 -1 3 65535 65535
- 1.02448 3 1 sctp 56 -------I 0 3.0 0.0 1 -1 3 65535 65535
r 1.03672 3 1 sctp 56 -------I 0 3.0 0.0 1 -1 3 65535 65535
+ 1.03672 1 0 sctp 56 -------I 0 3.0 0.0 1 -1 3 65535 65535
- 1.03672 1 0 sctp 56 -------I 0 3.0 0.0 1 -1 3 65535 65535
r 1.04896 1 0 sctp 56 -------I 0 3.0 0.0 1 -1 3 65535 65535
+ 1.04896 0 1 sctp 36 -------I 0 0.0 3.0 1 -1 4 65535 65535
- 1.04896 0 1 sctp 36 -------I 0 0.0 3.0 1 -1 4 65535 65535
r 1.0604 0 1 sctp 36 -------I 0 0.0 3.0 1 -1 4 65535 65535
+ 1.0604 1 3 sctp 36 -------I 0 0.0 3.0 1 -1 4 65535 65535
```

I have used command like this in ubuntu in ns2.

```
xgraph voip.tr
```

So how can I generate graph from the trace file?

Comment: Sounds like one of the lines is malformatted…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot give your trace file as a direct input to Xgraph. you have to give file with only two lines like

1   5

5 89

8 98  here first row is x axis 2nd is y axis for example save this file as graph.tr

now you can execute using **xgraph graph.tr** here instead of using random values you have to use your QOS valuse such as number of packets received or sent like that..

Answer (score 0):

xgraph can only be used with .xgr files. While executing the awk command add this (watch for the greater than symbol):

```
.... > anyname.xgr
```

Now you can use xgraph to plot, the command is:

```
xgraph anyname.xgr
```